# Python iteration in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm stuck on the following code:

```
nonsense = 'faxoyk'
R = {CHR : 'afokyx'.index(CHR) for CHR in nonsense}
print R
```

I'm new to python and I'm confused on how the keys and values get set, any insight into this process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which bit are you confused about? Does what is printed explain what the code does?

Comment: For explaining what the code does

Comment: I think people are wondering if you are confused specifically about list/dict comprehension, or if you are confused about dictionaries in general?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was about the list/dict comprehension, but you explained it perfectly down below. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dictionary comprehension is a feature that came after list comprehension, in python:
[List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

`nonsense` is a string. But it is a sequence object, so looping over it using `for CHR in nonsense` means you are looping over each character:

```
print [CHR for CHR in nonsense]
#['f', 'a', 'x', 'o', 'y', 'k']
```

The value part of your loop looks like this, by itself:

```
['afokyx'.index(CHR) for CHR in nonsense]
[1, 0, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

When you perform your dictionary comprehension, on each loop, `CHR` is a character from your string. You are asking that it set the key to the `CHR` and the value of that key to the index of the `CHR` in the string literal `"afokyx"`

Before python2.7 (before dict comprehension was introduced) it would have looked like this in a list comprehension:

```
print [(CHR, 'afokyx'.index(CHR)) for CHR in nonsense]
# [('f', 1), ('a', 0), ('x', 5), ('o', 2), ('y', 4), ('k', 3)]
R = dict((CHR, 'afokyx'.index(CHR)) for CHR in nonsense)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do keys and values get set in a dictionary?

Suppose you have dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

to set the value to a key you would do:

```
d['key'] = 'value'
```

to get:

```
 d['key']
```

You can set key and value pars during initialization like this:

```
 d = {'key':'value'}
```

But you have deal with dictionary comprehensions. It is a little advanced thing:

```
R = {CHR : 'faxoyk'.index(CHR) for CHR in nonsense}
```

You can understand this line like:

```
nonsense = 'faxoyk'
R = {}
for CHR in nonsense:
    R[CHR] = 'faxoyk'.index(CHR)

print R
```

Every string has method `index()`.

`string.index()` returns the index of certain letter in this string. For example: index of letter 'x' in string 'faxoyk' is 2, the index of letter 'f' is 0 and so on. This is because the indexing in iterable objects in Python starts out at 0.